# Ubuntu with no taskbar and everything 16.04

Tags: 16.04, taskbar

My windows xp pc to ubuntu pc does not have a taskbar but i tried the ubuntu unity thing and restarting the desktop and the cursor is an x. I don't have taskbar ontop the application but a Linux Mint gui works! Could anyone help me? (like today)

Comment: On Ubuntu you have the choice of which DESKTOP/GUI you wish to use.. You've not said which you're talking about, but it's possibly Unity 7 which was default in Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS.  Unity is one of >10 choices (some very popular, others not so). Your mention of Linux Mint however has got me confused as you're possibly off-topic, as Mint is neither Ubuntu, nor *flavor* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI:  Mint doesn't use the Unity 7 desktop; it's available with other choices (and only a small fraction of what Ubuntu offers; all of which are available on Ubuntu anyway),  so your question is likely DESKTOP related.. but the mention of Mint to me is unclear, meaning you maybe off-topic.  Also be aware 16.04 means the 2016-April release, which came with 5 years of supported life, which ends 2021-April, so it maybe not an ideal choice unless you're only planning on keeping it a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the new ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10. It'll work there. You're using a very very older version of ubuntu. I'd suggest upgrading, it'll fix your problem

Comment: With the limited info given here and no hardware info ram etc, given to say upgrade fixes everything is a very bad comment to make.

Comment: uhh my pc is a Lenovo Thinkpad windows xp